# For each to get keys and values from associative array doesn't return all keys and values if they share the same key name - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I'm reading a file that has this text:

```
Vélez Sarsfield|Zárate, Mauro|8|0|0|1|9
Estudiantes|Carrillo, Guido|5|1|0|2|8
Boca Juniors|Gigliotti, Emanuel|3|2|0|2|7
River Plate|Carbonero, Carlos Mario|4|2|0|0|6
Arsenal|Echeverría, Mariano|6|0|0|0|6
Olimpo|Valencia, José Adolfo|6|0|0|0|6
River Plate|Cavenaghi, Fernando Ezequiel|4|0|0|2|6
Boca Juniors|Riquelme, Juan Román|1|0|1|3|5
```

This is my code:

```
 <?php
            $handle = fopen("tp7-datos-goleadores.txt", "r");
            if ($handle) {
                while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
                    // process the line read.
                    //hago el asociativo
                    $porciones = explode("|", $line );
                    $arrAsociativo[$porciones[0]] =  $porciones[6];
                }
            
                fclose($handle);
            } else {
                echo "error al leer el archivo";
            } 

            foreach($arrAsociativo as $x => $x_value) {
                echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
                echo "<br>";
            }
    ?>
```

But it returns this on the html:

```
Key=V�lez Sarsfield, Value=9
Key=Estudiantes, Value=8
Key=Boca Juniors, Value=5
Key=River Plate, Value=6
Key=Arsenal, Value=6
Key=Olimpo, Value=6
```

As you can see, i have 2 Boca Juniors and 2 River Plate on my original text, but i only get one from each when i go through the array. Why is that?

Comment: You can't have two entries with the same key value.

Comment: @Nick So, i won't be able to show all of them?

Comment: You probably want a multidimensional array e.g. `$arrAsociativo[$porciones[0]][] =  $porciones[6];` but then `$x_value` will be an array, not a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could echo out your indexes through a loop.  Or alternatively, just create a new array with couplets.

```
<?php

$data =<<<DATA
Vélez Sarsfield|Zárate, Mauro|8|0|0|1|9
Estudiantes|Carrillo, Guido|5|1|0|2|8
Boca Juniors|Gigliotti, Emanuel|3|2|0|2|7
River Plate|Carbonero, Carlos Mario|4|2|0|0|6
Arsenal|Echeverría, Mariano|6|0|0|0|6
Olimpo|Valencia, José Adolfo|6|0|0|0|6
River Plate|Cavenaghi, Fernando Ezequiel|4|0|0|2|6
Boca Juniors|Riquelme, Juan Román|1|0|1|3|5
DATA;

$lines = preg_split('/\R/', $data);
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $rows[] = str_getcsv($line, '|');
}    

foreach($rows as $row) {
    $name_values[] = [$row[0], $row[6]];
}

foreach($name_values as list($name, $value)) {
    echo 'Name: ', $name, ', Value: ', $value, "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Name: Vélez Sarsfield, Value: 9
Name: Estudiantes, Value: 8
Name: Boca Juniors, Value: 7
Name: River Plate, Value: 6
Name: Arsenal, Value: 6
Name: Olimpo, Value: 6
Name: River Plate, Value: 6
Name: Boca Juniors, Value: 5
```

And the data structure of $name_values:

```
var_export($name_values);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Vélez Sarsfield',
    1 => '9',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Estudiantes',
    1 => '8',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Boca Juniors',
    1 => '7',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 'River Plate',
    1 => '6',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Arsenal',
    1 => '6',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Olimpo',
    1 => '6',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    0 => 'River Plate',
    1 => '6',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Boca Juniors',
    1 => '5',
  ),
)
```